# IStorageProviderItemPropertySource usability

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-runtime

I am trying to use class implementation for interface:
IStorageProviderItemPropertySource

I mean I have created a class `StorageProviderItemPropertySource : IStorageProviderItemPropertySource`. It has method `GetItemProperties(string itemPath)`
Also I have registered  StorageProviderItemPropertySource in system (in registry) so the system (Windows) can use it.
Maybe anyone knows or has an experience how to trigger the system to use this class and call it.
Oficial documentation did not help (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.provider.istorageprovideritempropertysource?view=winrt-19041).